# Big O for 2 functions that don't belong to one another

Tags: algorithm, big-o

> Give two functions f(n) and g(n) such that f(n) is not O(g(n)) and g(n) is not
>   O(f(n)).

When I started thinking about it, I thought of n and n^2. But, reading more I realized that if my function f is n and g is n^2, then f primary belongs to O(g(n)). So, I went back to square one. Any leads on how to go about it?

Comment: It is better to ask on https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's an exact duplicate. Someone has already had this task at the university

Answer (score 4):

Hint: your functions will need to be quite perverse. Try using sin(n).

Also consider constructing f and g extremely manually. Pick a bunch of intervals, like [1,2], [3,4], [5,6], ... where f is much bigger than g, and let g be much bigger than f on the other intervals.

Comment: Why so complicated?

Comment: @xenteros one, I gave multiple ways to do it. Two, the simplest functions possible will not work. Three, "just construct it so it's true" is not complicated at all as a method even if the end functions look complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Let f(n) = n%2, g(n) = 1-n%2. (Here x%y is as in C -- the remainder of x after dividing by y).

Neither f=O(g) nor g=O(f). For no odd n is there k>0 such that f(n)<=kg(n) since g(odd)=0 and f(odd)=1. Similarly, for no even n is there k>0 such that g(n)<=kf(n).

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to my mind.

```
f(n) = (-n)^n
g(n) = 2*n
```